# Use value of a local variable as global in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a variable that is obtain inside each block in thymeleaf. I want to send that variable to a certain method in my controller. The limitation is that the variable is obtain inside a block which makes it local, not accessible global.Hence I get an error while trying to use it. How can I move inside the scope to get the variable so as I can use it global in thymeleaf.

```
           <form th:action="@{/masomo/somo(date=${dateMpya.date})}" method="POST">
            <select id="date" name="date" required="true">
                <option value="none" selected disabled hidden > 
                    Select a Date     
               </option>   

            <th:block th:each="somoChagua : ${masomoChagua}">
            <option th:each="dateMpya: ${somoChagua}"  th:value="${dateMpya}" th:text="${dateMpya.date}" ></option>
            
            </th:block>

            </select>
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>  
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many different "dateMpya" objects for each "somoChagua".

But there is only one submit button.

So which "dateMpya" should be used for the submit button value?

I think what you are actually trying to do here is get the value of the "dateMpya" which the user selected in the drop-down. Is that right?

If that's the case there is no need to add any attributes to the submit button. You would access that value by using the name of the select element, which is "date".

EDIT: For the same reason you also need to remove the `(date=${dateMpya.date})` part of the form action as well. The value selected in the drop-down will automatically be submitted under the name of the select element "date", it does not need to be specified.

Comment: I have removed the attributes in submit button But still I am getting [Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'date' cannot be found on null]

Comment: Meaning that I can't still access that variable inside each block.Thanks for your response @shawnz

Comment: In that case, the problem is that one of the "dateMpya" objects is null, so it's an error to access the "dateMpya.date" property.

Comment: Actually, my mistake. I don't think the issue is actually a null dateMpya. I see the issue now: You also need to remove this ```(date=${dateMpya.date})``` in the form action, for the same reason as the submit button. "dateMpya" is not available outside the option element

Comment: It is not null, If I remove ** (date=${dateMpya.date})** from the form tag I can see the value from the **<option  th:text="${dateMpya.date}"> **  in my browser. The trick part is that I cannot access them outside the ** <th block> ** ,

Comment: Exactly @shwanz, now if I remove [ (date=${dateMpya.date}) ] from the form How would manage to post that value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value is posted because that is simply how HTML forms work. The select element's value will be posted to that URL with the name "date" because that is the name of the select element. No thymeleaf required for this behaviour

Comment: Okay. What can you suggest as alternative approach with thymeleaf.

Comment: What I mean to say is you don't need any thymeleaf special functionality to make it work. It will just work. There is no need to put anything special in the form action URL, it will work without that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229695/discussion-between-shawnz-and-gabriel-rogath).